# Does FCM provides any methods for topic subscription similar to onNewToken?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM sends an event via onNewToken() whenever an app is installed in a device. Do we have any similar methods available to capture the event for topic subscription or unsubscription, when a device is subscribed to a topic (or) unsubscribed from a topic?

Looking for a way to store the topic subscription details along with the deviceToken for every topic created for an app.

I could not see any such methods similar to onNewToken() for topic subscription events.

Answer (score 0):

Since the token can be refreshed by the server outside of the application's control, the server notifies the client when the topic changes.

Since your application itself subscribes to a topic, you already know when it happens and can track that yourself. So there is no server-to-client notification for when a client subscribes to a topic.